# Deactivate or remove the scrollbar on HTML

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to de-activate or remove the vertical `scrollbar` in an HTML page.
How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you really need it...

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Comment: Uhm, in a stylesheet or a `<style>` element.

Comment: good, but it just hide the scrollbar; if I use the keyboard it scroll down. How can I desactivate the scrolling down ?

Comment: The question was "remove the vertical scrollbar" and that did exactly that. You can try binding `keyup` or `keydown` to document and cancelling if the event code is equal to the down arrow, or reverting it with scrollTo(0,0) on the event handler.

Comment: Make a new question and specify exactly what you want please. Also state your level of Javascript please.

Comment: @AZIRAR, I suppose it's too much to hope for that you would realise this was a bad idea :-) The contents of the browser window can rightly be thought of as "yours", the browser itself (scroll bars, close buttons, navigation away from the site and so on) belongs to the user. What happens when they don't have enough vertical space to render your page and you won't let them scroll down?

Answer (score 7):

What I would try in this case is put this in the stylesheet

```
html, body{overflow:hidden;}
```

this way one disables the scrollbar, and as a cumulative effect they disable scrolling with the keyboard

Answer (score 4):

put this code in your html header:

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
        overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Doesn't "overflow: auto;" render exactly like the default behavior?

Comment: `overflow: visible` is the default behavior. I'm not saying that the answer is correct by the way.

Answer (score 4):

This makes it so if before there was a scrollbar then it makes it so the scrollbar has a display of none so you can't see it anymore. You can replace html to body or a class or ID. Hope it works for you :)

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Meder Omuraliev suggested to use an event handler and set scrollTo(0,0). This is an example for Wassim-azirar. Bringing it all together, I assume this is the final solution.

We have 3 problems: the scrollbar, scrolling with mouse, and keyboard.
This hides the scrollbar:

```
       html, body{overflow:hidden;}
```

Unfortunally, you can still scroll with the keyboard:
To prevent this, we can:

```
    function keydownHandler(e) {
var evt = e ? e:event;
  var keyCode = evt.keyCode;

  if (keyCode==38 || keyCode==39 || keyCode==40 || keyCode==37){ //arrow keys
e.preventDefault()
scrollTo(0,0);
}
}

document.onkeydown=keydownHandler;
```

The scrolling with the mouse just naturally doesn't work after this code, so we have prevented the scrolling.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7pes70/1/

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
```

in CSS

```
overflow: hidden;
```

you can also end scrolling for x or y separately

```
overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
```