# No Horizontal scrolling on website

Tags: html, css, image, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to position an image on my website that is wider than the resolution, which creates a horizontal scroll bar every time. I know someone who has a site with an image wider than the screen but his site doesn't cause you to scroll.

Does anyone know a code or a fix to the code that I can add to make the page unscrollable horizontally?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I meant "unscrollable" not "uncontrollable".

Comment: Hide overflow on the DOM Element where Image is being displayed

Comment: Have a look at the site you know that does what you want and copy how they have done it. Simples! Otherwise it's probably using the image as a background image or possibly using overflow: hidden on the image.

Comment: @user1266068 there is no need to comment to your own question in order to clarify since you can edit it.

Comment: duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034390/deactivate-or-remove-the-scrollbar-on-html

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow-x: hidden` to your `<html>` tag, or set the image as `background-image` instead, if the image is for design purpose and no content.

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```