# I Can't Figure Out How To Disable The Scroll Bar

Tags: html

I can't figure out how to disable the scroll bar for reasons about the website, can anyone help me?

`<iframe src="video" width="960"height="540" frameborder=0 ></iframe>`

Comment: You can find, it is answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034390/deactivate-or-remove-the-scrollbar-on-html

Comment: Did you even try anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```